# Flutter firebase auth security check

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter

I'm new to flutter and i'm using firebase auth as my authentication to the application. I'm from a php background and do I need to check if the user is logged in every new page like we check state in php. I'm using this method to handle auth,

```
Widget handleCurrentScreen() {

  return  StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return  Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Splash"),
            ),
            body: Text("Splash"),
          );
        } else {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return HomePage(_auth,_googleSignIn);
          }
          return  LoginScreen3();
        }
      }
  );
}
```

My question is here once I'm in this page HomePage(), Do I need to verify  auth as a good practice or to prevent from hackers?

Comment: You don need check every time after user log in, because your source routes should be HomePage, after user log in. LoginPage -> (user login) -> HomePage -> (user already logged) -> AnyPage . If you need check for any reason, use firebase.instance.currentUser != null .

Comment: @RubensMelo is it possible to check if the user is a new user or a registered user through handleCurrentScreen?

Comment: No, Isn't. You should check before submit form.

Comment: @RubensMelo handleCurrentScreen is the main widget which handles every thing from start. How can I redirect user to different screens based on if they are new or not

Comment: You can start the action on diferente screens. Let user choose if they already has an account or it is a new user.